# Problema com programa em C

Tags: c

Estou resolvendo um exercício que pede para ler um vetor de 20 posições e imprimir na tela excluindo valores repetidos, consegui resolver porem, ele esta mostrando os valores na tela varias vezes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int vet[20], x;
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
     printf("Digite um numero: ");
     scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
 }
 for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
 {
    for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
       if(vet[i] != vet[x])
       {
          printf("\n%d", vet[x]);
       }
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma pequena alteração em seu programa melhora esta solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int vet[20], x, repete;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Digite um numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        repete = 0
        for(x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            if(i != x && vet[i] == vet[x]) {
                repete++;
            }
        }
        if (repete == 0)
            printf("\n%d", vet[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo, tava quebrando a cabeça aqui por uma coisa tão simples kkkkk